# storing a string in a java program

Tags: java, mysql

I'm new to Java and I'm working on a project.

I was wondering if you could store a string in a compiled java program instead of in a file.. I already can query and access the database using JDBC.

I want there to be a special key that is unique to each user but I don't want it to be accessible to the user.. And once you restarted the computer that string would still be saved. Is this even possible? I'm not sure how this could be possible..

I appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're actually trying to achieve. Can you explain more on the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: sure, i'll try. I just want to have a unique hidden "key" for each user that they couldn't see. As they could give that key to another user and use my program.

Comment: You should post some example code ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Include what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck. See more info at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a special key? well you the easiest solution for that is like to create a a even number series or odd number, that will be different for each user.

Now for storing the data you save the data either in database or a text file,
Saving in a text file goes like this

First of all import this

```
import java.io.*;
```

Here is the code to create and save the data in a text file.

```
int userSpecialkey = 123;    

File f = new File("FileName.txt");

f.createNewFile();

BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));

bw.write(userSpecialkey);

bw.close();
```

an easy solution, For encrypting the data you can change the password sting into an char array then add some value to each index

```
String name = "shady";
String password = "OnePunchMan";

char[] encryptingPassword = password.toCharArray();


for(int i=0; i < encryptingPassword.length; i++){
     encryptingPassword[i] += '5';
}
```

This will change the char into a new char,
For decryption

```
for(int i=0; i < encryptingPassword.length; i++){
     encryptingPassword[i] -= '5';
}
```

`

Comment: Thanks for this but I don't want the users getting that "key"

Comment: Really sorry i totally forgot that part, im updating my answer

Answer (score 2):

Typically (but not always) a compiled java program is distributed as a .jar (or .war, or .ear). These are compressed 'archive' files containing java class files and other things needed to run an application.

The .jar is just a zip file. Users can unzip it or read its contents using built in features of Windows, Linux, Mac OS. So, while it is possible to write data into the .jar, it's very accessible to users, and may even be easy to interpret.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i was thinking of using a wrapper like JWrapper so it isn't as easy to access the .jar.

Comment: This is a really hacky thing to do, I'm reluctant to suggest how to do it. Might be better if you describe the problem rather than the solution. If you just want to store some obscured or encrypted data you don't need to write to the executable to do that. On windows at least I believe the OS will lock the executable to prevent writes until you are done running. It sounds possible to make this happen with a second executable and a bunch of hassle, but I would not want to own that code.

Comment: After some thought Encryption is what I want, thanks!